# Update column value based on the multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have a table example: (Col3 is bit datatype)

```
col1 | col2 | col3 
____________________
abc  |  xyz |  0
abc  |  xyz |  1
abc  |  xyz |  0
abc  |  xyz |  0
```

I want to select distinct from the table except for col3 and update col3 value to 0 if col3 values are different. (If all col3 values are same then distinct will return distinct rows).

Here I am expecting the output to be:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 
____________________
abc  |  xyz |  0
```

Any help?

**Edit**

When col3 values are same:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 
____________________
abc  |  xyz |  0
abc  |  xyz |  0
abc  |  xyz |  0
abc  |  xyz |  0

col1 | col2 | col3 
____________________
abc  |  xyz |  1
abc  |  xyz |  1
abc  |  xyz |  1
abc  |  xyz |  1
```

***EDIT***

Further if I want to update only few of the rows then how can that be done? Example:

If there exists data :

```
col1 | col2 | col3 
____________________
abc  |  xyz |  0
abc  |  xyz |  1
abc  |  xyz |  1
abc  |  xyz |  0
qwe  |  asd |  1
qwe  |  asd |  0
qwe  |  asd |  0
qwe  |  asd |  0
```

Expected output:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 
____________________
 abc  |  xyz |  0
 qwe  |  asd |  0
```

Comment: . . Can you show an example where the values are all the same?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Please check my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following query using `row_number()` function, `cte` and `inner join` as shown below.

Note: If you want to update values with a duplicate one and keep one from those entries as it is in that case you do not need to join with the table again.

```
create table SampleTable( col1 varchar(10)
, col2 varchar(10)
, col3 bit)

insert into SampleTable values
('abc', 'xyz', 0),
('abc', 'xyz', 1),
('abc', 'xyz', 0),
('abc', 'xyz', 0)

--Before update
select * from SampleTable

--Getting rows with duplicate 
; with cte as (SELECT col1
 , col2
 , col3
 , row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, col3 order by (select null)) as cnt
FROM SampleTable
)UPDATE t 
set t.col1 = t.col1
, t.col2 = t.col2
, t.col3 = 1
from SampleTable t
inner join cte on t.col1 = cte.col1
and t.col2 = cte.col2 and t.col3 = cte.col3
and cnt > 1

--After update
select * from SampleTable
```

Here is the live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7305e3d0ff3d704e8d82425c017f82de) demo.

Here is an another way using `exists`.

Second approach

```
update t1
set t1.col1 = t1.col1
, t1.col2 = t1.col2
, t1.col3 = 1
from SampleTable t1
where exists (select 1
              from SampleTable t2
              where t1.col1 = t2.col1
                and t1.col2 = t2.col2
                and t1.col3 = t2.col3
              group by col1, col2, col3
              having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I want to modify the query as per new enhancement. Please check the edit.

Comment: @Arti Please check this demo link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=edef1f90ba5352d30bc030c49b6f1435

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it works. It will not cause any performance issue right?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select distinct col1, col2, 0 as col3
from t;
```

Or perhaps:

```
select col1, col2, 0 as col3
from t
group by col1, col2
having min(col3) <> max(col3)
union all
select col1, col2, col3
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t
                  where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 = t.col2 and
                        t2.col3 <> t.col3
                 );
```

This can also be expressed with window functions:

```
select col1, col2,
       (case when min_col3 = max_col3 then max(col3) else 0 end) as col3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3) as seqnum,
             max(col3) over (partition by col1, col2) as max_col3,
             min(col3) over (partition by col1, col2) as min_col3
     from t
    ) t
group by col1, col2, min_col3, max_col3,
         (case when min_col3 = max_col3 then seqnum else 0 end)
```

Comment: Col3 is bit datatype

Comment: @Arti . . . Then cast it to an int.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I want to modify the query as per new enhancement. Please check the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can `group by col1, col2` and a `case` expression for `col3`:

```
select col1, col2,
  case when min(cast(col3 as int)) = max(cast(col3 as int)) then 1 else 0 end col3
from tablename
group by col1, col2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=af4cd9e8d50f92c5c88b9f6a7e75f308).
Results:

```
> col1 | col2 | col3
> :--- | :--- | ---:
> abc  | xyz  |    0
```

Comment: Will this work for Bit datstype? Col3 is a bit type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I want to modify the query as per new enhancement. Please check the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
UPDATE t
       SET t.col3 = (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                       FROM table t1 
                                       WHERE t1.col1 = t.col1 AND 
                                             t1.col2 = t.col2 AND
                                             t1.col3 <> t.col3
                                      ) 
                          THEN 0 ELSE 1
                     END) 
FROM table t;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I want to modify the query as per new enhancement. Please check the edit.

Comment: @Arti. . . Edit the question after answers would interact down-votes. So, i would suggests to ask other question referenced from this.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example you can group by(col1,col2) and then take min(col3)